# Many-to-Many JSON API URI naming

Tags: uri, naming-conventions, json-api

I'm wondering if the following naming convention would correctly fit the [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/) standard, as it is not specifically mentioned anywhere that I can find.

Given a many to many relationship between accounts and products, with an account-product resource storing pivot data between the two.

I would to know how to handle the **/api/v1/accounts/1/products** relationship resource

**account > account-product > product**

URLs:

**/api/v1/accounts**: returns **account** resources

**/api/v1/account-product**s: returns **account-product** resources

**/api/v1/accounts/1/products**: returns **account-product** resources

OR

**/api/v1/accounts/1/products**: return **product** resources related to the account

---

The two arguments here being this:

Option 1: account/1/products should return the link between the accounts and the products as it should essentially act as the ID should essentially act as a hyphen e.g. account/1/products really means account-products.

Option 2: account/1/products should returns products related to the account and also include the account-products resource as a mandatory relationship because the resource in the URI is product, not account-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON:API specification is agnostic about URL design. Therefore it mostly depends where these URLs are used. But JSON:API spec comes with some [recommendations on URL design](https://jsonapi.org/recommendations/#urls). I assume that you follow that ones. Especially that `/api/v1/accounts/1/products` is used as [related resource link](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links), e.g.

```
{
  "type": "accouts",
  "id": "1",
  "relationships": {
    "products": {
      "links": {
        "related": "/api/v1/accounts/1/products"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In that case the spec is quite clear about what should be returned:

> **Related Resource Links**
>
> A “related resource link” provides access to resource objects linked
>   in a relationship. When fetched, the related resource object(s) are
>   returned as the response’s primary data.
>
> For example, an article’s comments relationship could specify a link
>   that returns a collection of comment resource objects when retrieved
>   through a GET request.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-related-resource-links

From how you describe your data structure an `account` has many `account-products`, which belongs to a `product`. So it should return the related `account-products`. You may include the `products` they belong to by default.

What may confuse you is the concept of intermediate relations like "Has One Through" in some ORMs (e.g. Eloquent). The naming `account-products` suggest that this might be an example of such. Something like that is not supported by JSON:API spec. Intermediate relationships should modeled using a normal resource type. So in your case `account-products` would be a normal resource type like `accounts` and `products`.

Comment: Great answer. I was actually leaning the other way but this has cleared some stuff up. You are also correct that we are using Eloquent! So are you saying that its would make sense that api/v1/accounts/1/products would return account-product resources which would be an amalgamation of the product resource with the pivot data?

Comment: Thanks. It depends on your concrete data structure if it makes sense to merge these two resource into one. In general I would not recommend that approach cause you may face issues later. Especially if you are also dealing with products independently of the pivot data you would have duplicated information. In most cases it makes sense to represent the pivot data by a dedicated resource type. You could use sideloading by default to prevent additional round trips. So there wouldn't be much overhead.

Comment: Right. And when you say side loading do you mean including the data by default?

Comment: Yes. To use the terms of the spec, I mean that you may want to return a [compound document](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) by default. That's explicitly allowed by the spec as long as you respect an [`include` query parameter](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) if it exists. Would be great if you mark the answer as accepted if you don't have any additional questions / need for clarification.

Comment: Of coarse. Thanks for the advice.